# Выгрузка картинки из базы на страницу сайта

Tags: linux, php, html, javascript, css

Всем привет! подскажите, вот есть у меня база, в ней таблица из 3х полей - `id`, `pic`, `name`. В `id` хранится номер, в `pic` хранится изображение, в `name` - имя изображения. Вопрос такой: как мне вывести хранящиеся в поле `pic` картинки на страницу сайта?

```
$query = "select * from tab1 where name like '%".$name."%'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo '<p><strong>Count result : '.$num_results.'</p>';
  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
  {
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<p><strong>'.($i+1).'. Id : ';
     echo stripslashes($row['id']);
     echo '<br />Image: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['pic']);
     <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?=base64_encode($row['pic'])?>" />
     echo '<br />Image name: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['name']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего так:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?=base64_encode($row['pic'])?>" />
```

Чуть сложнее но правильнее:

```
<img src="/image.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>" />
```

И файле image.php получайте картинку по **$_GET['id']** из базы и выводите ее через **echo**

Comment: а в первом варианте где кавычки кончаются? после base64? если да, то не работает.И перед завершением тега тоже. Картинку храню в blob.

Comment: пардон, исправил. 

Кстати,  надеюсь вы догадались, что предполагается что вы уже вытащили картинку из БД и положили ее в массив $row ?

Comment: Если так, то не работает:  
$query = "select * from tab1 where name like '%".$name."%'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo '<p><strong>Count result : '.$num_results.'</p>';
  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
  {
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<p><strong>'.($i+1).'. Id : ';
     echo stripslashes($row['id']);
     echo '<br />Image: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['pic']);
     <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?=base64_encode($row['pic'])?>" />
     echo '<br />Image name: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['name']);
  }

Comment: Эм, а зачем же вы HTML код в PHP затолкали?
Хоть так чтоли сделайте:

echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['pic']).'" />';

Comment: Спасибо все получилось.